# Converting regex whitespace characters from list into string

Tags: python, regex

So i want to convert regex whitespaces into a string for example

```
list1 = ["Hello","\s","my","\s","name","\s","is"]
```

And I want to convert it to a string like

```
"Hello my name is"
```

Can anyone please help. 
But also if there was characters such as 
     "\t" 
how would i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list = ["Hello","\s","my","\s","name","\s","is"]
str1 = ''.join(list).replace("\s"," ")
```

**Output :**

```
>>> str1
'Hello my name is'
```

**Update :**

If you have something like this `list1 = ["Hello","\s","my","\s","name","\t","is"]` then you can use multiple replace

```
>>> str1 = ''.join(list).replace("\s"," ").replace("\t"," ")
>>> str1
'Hello my name is'
```

or if it's only `\t`

```
str1 = ''.join(list).replace("\t","anystring")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend using the join string function mentioned in one of the earlier answers, as it is less verbose. However, if you absolutely needed to use regex in order to complete the task, here's the answer:

```
import re

list1 = ["Hello","\s","my","\s","name","\s","is"]
list_str = ''.join(list1)

updated_str = re.split('\\\s', list_str)
updated_str = ' '.join(updated_str)

print(updated_str)
```

Output is:

```
'Hello my name is'
```

In order to use raw string notation, replace the 5th line of code with the one below:

```
updated_str = re.split(r'\\s', list_str)
```

Both will have the same output result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need regular expressions for that:

```
s = ' '.join([item for item in list if item is not '\s'])
```

Please note that `list` is an invalid name for a variable in python as it conflicts with the `list` function.

Comment: What do you mean? There is only a string '\s' in the example data and the data is a list, not a string at all. How should regular expressions help in this case?